# What exactly is the use of ARIA "role" in html?

Tags: html, wai-aria

I saw the documentation for ARIA 'role' but couldn't understand it. What exactly does it do? Say, I use it in a table like this:

```
<td role='button'>text</td>
```

does it mean that this cell will act like a button? Can someone explain this in simpler terms?

Comment: The "role" and "aria-*" attributes are used for accessibility purpose so that the screen reader can read the page accordingly as we want and these attributes do nothing with the html look and feel.

Comment: @Sujata Chanda : ok, so it'll neither appear nor act as a button for normal screens?

Comment: Yes it will neither appear nor act as a button for normal screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role) which says:

> The button role should be used for clickable elements that trigger a
>   response when activated by the user. On its own, role="button" can
>   make any element (e.g. `<p>, <span> or <div>`) appears as a button
>   control to a screen reader. Additionally, this role can be used in
>   combination with the aria-pressed attribute in order to create toggle
>   buttons.

Also see the **note**

> Where possible, **it is recommended to use native HTML buttons**
>   (`<button>, <input type="button" /> and <input type="image" />`) rather
>   than the button role, as native HTML buttons are more widely supported
>   by older user agents and assistive technology. Native HTML buttons
>   also support keyboard and focus requirements by default, without need
>   for additional customization.

The w3.org also has a detailed explanation of [aria-role](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#aria-roles)

Comment: but when i tried it in <span>, the text inside span didn't look like a button, and even when i added a listener to it, it didn't respond.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, ARIA is for accessibility and the role attribute won't have an effect on normal browsers.

One of the most simple and functional ways to implement ARIA roles is the use of Landmarks. Some ARIA roles are Landmarks, which allow users to jump to specific parts of the page in screen readers. Some blind users find this helpful as it helps them navigate quickly. Support and behaviour in different screen readers is described [here](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2011/07/html5-accessibility-chops-aria-landmark-support/).